# CSS Conditional styling if Component is of max-width: 600px

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

not the screen I want to apply this if the component is of width 600px
I'm trying to change some styling if the component is in a Modal I only want to change flex-direction from column to row-reverse so I can't see a point in doing another component
my code

```
const wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
}
`
```

This obviously doesn't since it is checking the screen

Comment: Maybe look into whether browser support for _container queries_ is broad enough for your purposes first of all. https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using CSS [`@container`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container) queries

Using container queries requires creating a parent container element that the `Wrapper` component can be rendered into. This is supported in `styled-components@6`.

Example:

```js
const Container = styled.div`
  container-type: inline-size;
`;
```

```js
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  @container (max-width: 600px) {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
`;
```

Usage:

```
<Container>
  <Wrapper>
    ...wrapped content...
  </Wrapper>
</Container>
```

Or a bit more succinct using an anonymous inline function:

```
const Div = styled((props) => (
  <div className="container">
    <div {...props} />
  </div>
))`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  @container (max-width: 600px) {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }

  .container:has(> &) {
    container-type: inline-size;
  }
`;
```

Usage:

```
<Wrapper>
  ...wrapped content...
</Wrapper>
```

## Using Javascript to measure the DOM

If your project or environment doesn't support container queries then you will need to measure the `div` HTML node to check its width to see if it is less than or equal to 600 pixels or not.

Here's an example implementation using a wrapper component to do the measuring of the styled `div` element:

Custom hook to measure DOMNode by React ref and return its width.

```js
const useElementWidth = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [width, setWidth] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      setWidth(ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    };

    handler();

    window.addEventListener("resize", handler, true);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handler, true);
    };
  }, []);

  return {
    ref,
    width
  };
};
```

Wrapper to attach ref and set CSS classname for when the "media query" condition is met.

```
import { clsx } from "clsx";

const Wrapper = (props) => {
  const { ref, width } = useElementWidth();

  return (
    <InnerWrapper
      ref={ref}
      className={clsx({ mobile: width <= 600 })}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

The original `div` styled component.

```
const InnerWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  &.mobile {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
`;
```

Element under 600px

[image]

Element over 600px

[image]

Element in parent element with max-width of 700px

[image]

Comment: I know this would do the trick but I don't want unnecessary setStates
can it be done in styled-components or even normal css

Comment: @Zein I was able to get container queries working. Updated answer to include both implementations.